# 'FK.X' on table 'X' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Where?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

In my configurations fluent api:

```
internal class AuditoriaConfiguracao : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<Auditoria>
{
    public AuditoriaConfiguracao()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.CriadoPor);
        HasMany(p => p.Feedbacks).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}


internal class ResultadoAuditoriaConfiguracao : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<ResultadoAuditoria>
{
    public ResultadoAuditoriaConfiguracao()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.CriadoPor);
        HasMany(p => p.Motivos).WithMany(p => p.ResultadosAuditorias).Map(m => m.ToTable("ResultadosAuditoriaMotivos"));
    }
}


internal class MotivoConfiguracao : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<Motivo>
{
    public MotivoConfiguracao()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.CriadoPor);
    }
}

internal class VendaConfiguracao : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<Venda>
{
    public VendaConfiguracao()
    {   
        HasRequired(p => p.CriadoPor);
        HasMany(p => p.Auditorias).WithRequired(p => p.Venda).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

When running the command `Update-Database` the following error occurs:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ResultadoAuditoriaMotivo_dbo.Motivos_Motivo_Id' on table 'ResultadoAuditoriaMotivo' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I know that the error is probably in `ResultadoAuditoriaConfiguracao` but do not know how to solve it.

Could you help me?

Comment: Its happening because TSQL detects multiple ways or a cycle when trying to delete a record, cause by delete on cascade. Are those all your tables? I can see is an audit system, nothing should be erase, so you can solve it setting all the delete on cascade on false.

Comment: Even setting all `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` the error persists.
Some records can be deleted.

Comment: Are those all your tables?